# Passing Javascript object to PHP using post on submit and store data in mySQL DB

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I'm having issues posting JS object into a PHP page on submit and then store it into mySQL db.

Here's the script:

```
var idToDb = [];
var nameToDb = [];
var friendToDb ={};
$('.btn-add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-info btn-success');
    $(this).toggleClass('friend-selected');
    $(this).html($(this).html() == "Selected" ? "Add" : "Selected");         
    addOrRemove(idToDb, $(this).parent().data('id'));
    addOrRemove(nameToDb, $(this).parent().data('name'));
    friendToDb = _.object(idToDb, nameToDb)
```

I want to post this array **"friendToDb"** to a separate PHP page using post after clicking submit button and then store it in mySQL db.

Here's what I'm trying to post in PHP:

```
<form method="post" action="friend_input.php">
    <div id="submitBtnRow" class="row top-plus">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" value="SUBMIT">Submit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /submitBtnRow -->
</form>
```

And then in **friend_input.php**, I'm trying to fetch **friendToDb** and store in mySQL db and this I'm not sure how to do.

Please advice me how this should be done.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of `$.ajax`?..

Comment: What issues are you having? Where is the code that tries to submit it?

Comment: If i am not wrong `friendToDb` is an object not an array.Your code says so.

Comment: @NabeelSheikh Yeah sorry that's an object. And I'm not aware of ajax at all.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I forgot to include that. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Make `form action=""` and Use ajax to pass your object to php:

```
$.ajax({
url:"friend_input.php",
type:"post",
data:{value:JSON.stringify(friendToDb)},   //Converts a JavaScript value to a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string.
success:function(result){
// response from php page
}
});
```

In php page:

```
echo json_decode($_POST['value']);  //Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but how do I make sure that this happens only after I click the submit button? And could you also explain what does "//response from php page" means? Thanks

Comment: Use this function once `friendToDb` is declared. i.e after assigning value to  `friendToDb`. "//response from php page" means the response that your getting from your php page.i.e in this case `$_POST['value']` will be displayed if you `alert` variable `result`

Comment: Ok. So I did what you told me and after I click the submit button, the page gets redirected to friend_input.php and I get an error: "Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\project-1\friend_input.php on line 37"

Comment: Is it getting redirected via ajax or form action??

Comment: It should get redirected via form action because the variable friendToDb is dynamic and is not final until user clicks submit button.

Comment: So you want form action and ajax to work simultaneously?? whick is not possible..

Comment: So then how do I post to PHP on clicking SUBMIT?

Comment: Thanks I did that, but again I got the same error: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\project-1\friend_input.php on line 36

Comment: I hadn't used alert before. But now I've inserted it in and this is the error I'm getting: <br/>
<b>Catchable fatal error</b.: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in <b> C:\xampp\htdocs\project-1\friend_input.php</b> on line <b>36</b><br/>

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your form

```
<input id="friendDb" name="friendDb" type="hidden" />
```

Then using use

```
$("#friendDb").val();
```

To set the value before posting to your script.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the connection between <input> tag and setting the variable $("#friendDb").val();? I followed your approach and changed the input tag and used another variable to store #friendToDb and tried to echo it in php. But nothing was displayed.